# How to debug your Release APK or any APK in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-release

I want to debug by release **APK** or any **APK** that I have built from the Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 01: Go to `File`  and then click `Profile or debug APK`

Step 02: Then a dialog will open. choose your `APK` and hit **OK**

[image]

Step 03: Then choose your device and start debugging your APK.

[image]